# How can I align unsorted list horizontly ?

Tags: html, css, list

I need to make a kind of time line like [this one](http://www.vintagesynth.com/timeline/), the best I get is to vertically align the item:

**CSS**

```
ul {
       list-style-type: none;
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #000;
       background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #EBEFF9;
       border: 1px solid #D9E4FF;
       border-radius: 4px;
       display: block;
       margin: 2px;
       padding: 3px;
       max-width:300px;
   }

h3 {
       color: #32ff12;
       background: #000000;
       max-width: 440px;
       border-radius: 4px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>March</h3>
<ul>
    <li>1 a 3 - Fronteira</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>10 a 13 -Belver</li>
</ul>
<h3>April</h3>
<ul>
    <li>1 a 3 - Silves</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>10 a 13 -Porto</li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas of how to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `div` "wrapper" to your `ul` ans set it to [`float: left;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float). Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sPp52/2/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">    
<h3>March</h3>
    <!-- If you have to use a list, you can use it like this.
         Each <li> is an item of the list <ul> -->
    <ul> 
        <li>1 a 3 - Fronteira</li>
        <li>10 a 13 -Belver</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">    
<h3>April</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>1 a 3 - Silves</li>
        <li>10 a 13 -Porto</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* css reset */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* here you go */
.wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 12px;
    width: 200px;
}

h3 {
    color: #32ff12;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 4px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #EBEFF9;
    border: 1px solid #D9E4FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 4px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping your elements in a floated div can get you there.

```
.box {float: left; margin-right: 5px;}
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/6hwAT/

Answer (score 0):

You can right click on [that page](http://www.vintagesynth.com/timeline/) and select `View Page Source` menu (if you are using `Chrome`) or similar menus in other browsers. Then you could see the source code for CSS and Javascript internally provided by developer of that page. For example the css code for styling timeline is:

```
/* Timeline styling */#timeline {    margin: 10px 0 8px 0;    padding: 20px;    overflow: auto;    border: 2px solid #D9E4FF;   font-size: 11px;    cursor: move;   background: url("images/vsewall.jpg") top right no-repeat;}.tl-events {    width: 9600px; /*210 per column*/    list-style: none;    padding: 0;    margin: 0;}.tl-events li {    float: left;    width: 200px;    margin-right: 10px;}.tl-events ul {    list-style: none;    margin: 0;    padding: 0;}.tl-events ul li a {    text-decoration: none;    color: #000;    background: #EBEFF9;    border: 1px solid #D9E4FF;    -moz-border-radius: 4px;    border-radius: 4px;    display: block;    margin: 2px;    padding: 3px;}.tl-events ul li a:hover,.tl-events ul li a:focus {    outline: 0;    background: #C2CCE4;    border: 1px solid #B0BACF;}.tl-events ul li.highlight a {    background-color: #FFFF99;}.tl-events li h3.next {  background-color: #EBEFF9;  font-size: 120%;    padding: 3px 3px 3px 12px;  margin-right: -20px;    margin-left: 10px;  background-image: url("images/arrow.png");  background-position: 103% 50%;  background-repeat: no-repeat;   overflow: hidden;
```

I copied and pasted this code from the link you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `UL`s with floated `DIV`s elements so that you will be able to enjoy from columns syle.

Take a look at my solution at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ynevet/cJDT9/

**CSS:**

```
.float-left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 12px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #EBEFF9;
    border: 1px solid #D9E4FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 3px;
    max-width:300px;
}
h3 {
    color: #32ff12;
    background: #000000;
    max-width:440px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="float-left">
<h3>March</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>1 a 3 - Fronteira</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>10 a 13 -Belver</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="float-left">
<h3>April</h3>
    <ul>
        <li>1 a 3 - Silves</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>10 a 13 -Porto</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each month title and it's accompanying list within a container, apply a width to this container and float it to the left.

As the months can be considered a list as well, it would make sense semantically to have an ordered list, with each month as a list item (which would constitute the container) and then the unordered list nested within each ordered list item, e.g.:

```
<ol>
    <li>
        <h3>March</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>1 a 3 - Fronteira</li>
            <li>10 a 13 -Belver</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h3>April</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>1 a 3 - Silves</li>
            <li>10 a 13 -Porto</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Then the CSS:

```
ol > li {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    list-style: none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #EBEFF9;
    border: 1px solid #D9E4FF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 3px;
}

h3 {
    color: #32ff12;
    background: #000000;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/redwar/p3N4Q/)